# How do I chroot LDAP users in proftpd AND allow a single LDAP admin user access to everything?

Tags: proftpd

I use proftpd to host an FTP server.  By default, all users are chrooted to /var/ftp/%u (where %u is their username).  This is done by using the DefaultRoot directive.

I now have a need to provide an "admin" user that can login and crawl the entire tree, starting in /var/ftp.  I can't seem to find a way to bypass the DefaultRoot directive.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched all of the proftpd directives and was not able to find a solution that worked with LDAP users.  To work around this, I created a second VirtualHost that listens on a different port than the main VirtualHost.  The new VirtualHost authenticates against a different LDAP group than the main one, and chroots users to /var/ftp.

I did have to add a 'DefaultChdir /var/ftp' entry to the new VirtualHost so that admin users would start in /var/ftp instead of /var/ftp/%u.

Comment: This is the best solution I could come up with.  I'll leave the question unsolved for awhile in case someone else has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. If you'd read the [documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html) you'd see that if group name is prepended with "!" then DefaultRoot is not enabled for that group.

```
DefaultRoot ~ !admin
```

Comment: I did read the documentation.  What I did not do is specify that I am using the mod_ldap module.  The group option applies to groups in /etc/passwd, but I'm using LDAP users that don't have a UID, or a GID.  When I tried using the group flag, it ignored my LDAP groups.